# Получение размера данных C++

Tags: c++, sizeof

Вопрос. Есть функция. Она берет из памяти данные в определенном количестве (16к слов), обрабатывает и выдает данные данные в другом количестве, сохраняя их в память. Далее мне надо работать с данными, которые в памяти.
Вопрос: **Как узнать размер данных полученных после функции? Они хранятся в переменной же.** Пытался реализовать в следующем стиле:

```
    conv((long long (*)[h][w])in, (long long (*)[h][w][in_c])B, (long long (*)[y][x])out, add+shift, mul+shift );
    Copy(reinterpret_cast<int*>(out),reinterpret_cast<int*>(output[s_data_shift]), sizeof(out)/64);
```

Где conv - функция рабочая, а Copy функция копирования данных с аргументами:(source, destination, word(именно в словах!)). Пытаюсь узнать размер выходной переменной out с помощью sizeof() и делю на 64, чтобы получить количество слов. Доходя до этапа определенного далее по программе, все виснет из-за некорректности данных. **Правильно ли я определяю размер?**

Comment: `out` это же указатель? `sizeof` указателя будет 32 или 64 (в зависимости от платформы).

Comment: Размер обьекта по ссылке - заранее неизвестен. Если размер плавающий - его всегда "пробрасывают" через а)дополнительный параметр или б)поле класса. Если размер обьект постоянный - то можно а или б или с)template-параметр. Так же можно добавить что бывает "вычисляемый" размер, но это редко используется, что б не тратить время на вычисление.

Comment: @nick_n_a размер динамический. Пробрасывать через define или просто поле класса прокидывать? Спасибо, как идея.

Comment: через define можно что-то пробросить разве?)

Comment: define и template в даном случае работают почти одинаково, с разницей, что template более осязаема, синтаксиз разный, template-параметры видны в дебаггере. Да, размер можно пробросить через template не хуже чем через define.

Comment: @nick_n_a благодарю вас. Я бы даже рекомендовал это как ответ добавить, так как ваши комментарии ответ на вопрос!

Comment: "Где conv - функция рабочая,..." - функция-то может и "рабочая", но, судя по количеству явных преобразований в вызове, вызов не очень "рабочий".  "...и делю на 64, чтобы получить количество слов". Откуда взялось `64`? `sizeof` дает размер в байтах. Какой у вас размер "слова"? 64 байта? Почему в вопросе отсутствуют объявления `in`, `out`, `B`???

Comment: @nick_n_a: Ничего не понял. Что значит "define и template в данном случае работают", если автор вопроса ясно сказал, что "размер динамический", т.е. на стадии компиляции не известный? Ни `define`, ни `template` в таком случае не применимы в принципе.

Comment: @AnT скорее всего размер одинаковый - 16к слов, а вот адрес в памяти - разный (т.е. под 16к слов выделяется динамическая память).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер по указателю в памяти - заранее не известен. При обработке данных там где нужен размер выбирается один из нескольких способов.

1. Создаётся локальная константа либо переменная, туда заносится размер, далее во все методы где участвует размер - добавляется ещё один параметр. Размер передаётся через параметр функции/метода. (например та же функция read FileRead и т п).
2. Размер передаётся через поле структуры или класса (например как в классе string).
3. Размер калькуляционный - вычисляется.
4. Размер передаётся через #define или template

C #define думаю всё понятно `#define my_size 10*4*sizeof(long)` и пошли.

Теперь как передать размер через template. Для метода это делается например так

```
template<int N, int M> my_read(void* data) {
   readbytes(myfile, data, sizeof(long)*N*M);
   }
```

Размер можно вкладывать в аргуметы

```
template<int N, int M> my_read(long (*data)[N][M]){
   readbytes(myfile, data, sizeof(long)*N*M);
   readbytes(myfile, data, sizeof(*data)); // Даже так

   }
```

На каждый template как правило создается отдельная реализация кода, поэтому подставлять в template можно только константы. Желательно не делать 100 вариантов-больших template функций, т.к. это приведёт к раздутию кода. Похожие template-конструкции встречал в видеокодеках и кодеках изображения, например в jpegd кодеке.